# why app is showing white screen in release mode?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have upload an ios app developed with flutter on appstore for testing in testflight mode ,but it show white screen on some device  when i used to test it ,but on some of the devices it worked fine, what will be the issue

**This is my splash screen file**

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
          ),
          Image.asset(
            'image/asset/image.jpg',
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.2,//200
          ),
        
          Image.asset(
            'image/asset/adms.jpg',
            width: 250,
            height: 170,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Can you upload an image?

Comment: This is very generic, please add image and more description and the devices which are working and which are not and operating system if this issue is coming for a specific version.

Comment: "Hey, my app isn't working. Can you tell me why?"
You need to upload an image, the stacktraces, device that crashes, some code...

Comment: this can happen if you use Expanded widget outside of Column () and Row (). the Expanded widget should only be used to wrap the widgets that are between the Column and Row

Comment: But why it is running for some of the devices....

Comment: Both the devices are same , device is iphone xr

Comment: But one shows white screen but on another it is showing no issue  and running fine

Comment: if the app is in debug mode, everything is working fine. But if the application is in release mode, and you install it on a device, you will see a blank screen if you don't use the Expanded widget well

Comment: Normally, the splash code you have above shouldn't cause a problem. We can see the contents of the main.dart file